# GCC function padding value

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Whenever I compile C or C++ code with optimizations enable,d GCC aligns functions to a 16-byte boundary (on IA-32). If the function is shorter than 16 bytes, GCC pads it with some bytes, which don't seem to be random at all:

```
19:   c3                      ret
1a:   8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
```

It always seems to be either `8d b6 00 00 00 00 ...` or `8d 74 26 00`.

Do function padding bytes have any significance?

Comment: My understanding is/was that GCC uses 0s for function alignment padding, but as I can't point you to a source that's probably not very helpful...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The padding is created by the assembler, not by gcc. It merely sees a `.align` directive (or equivalent) and doesn't know whether the space to be padded is inside a function (e.g. loop alignment) or between functions, so it must insert `NOP`s of some sort. Modern x86 assemblers use the largest possible `NOP` opcodes with the intention of spending as few cycles as possible if the padding is for loop alignment.

Personally, I'm extremely skeptical of alignment as an optimization technique. I've never seen it help much, and it can definitely hurt by increasing the total code size (and cache utilization) tremendously. If you use the `-Os` optimization level, it's off by default, so there's nothing to worry about. Otherwise you can disable all the alignments with the proper `-f` options.

Comment: Looks like that's correct. `-S` output does not have padding no-ops.

Answer (score 3):

The assembler first sees an `.align` directive. Since it doesn't know if this address is within a function body or not, it cannot output NULL `0x00` bytes, and must generate `NOP`s (`0x90`).

However:

```
lea    esi,[esi+0x0] ; does nothing, psuedocode: ESI = ESI + 0
```

executes in fewer clock cycles than

```
nop
nop
nop
nop
nop
nop
```

If this code happened to fall within a function body (for instance, loop alignment), the `lea` version would be much faster, while still "doing nothing."

Answer (score 2):

The instruction `lea 0x0(%esi),%esi` just loads the value in `%esi` into `%esi` - it's no-operation (or `NOP`), which means that if it's executed it will have no effect.

This just happens to be a single instruction, 6-byte NOP.  `8d 74 26 00` is just a 4-byte encoding of the same instruction.

Comment: But it's not a reachable instruction (being after `ret`), is it?

Comment: @Alex B: It's not directly reachable (but it could be jumped to).  There is often reason to produce executable padding within functions, so it's probable that GCC just reuses the same padding algorithm for end of functions.