# Why are there some NOP paddings at the end of each function?

Tags: gcc, assembly, compiler-construction, binary, llvm

When objdump the binary, there usually some NOP paddings like

```
66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00    data32 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

or

```
0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00   nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

or

```
66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

at the end of each function. What is the purpose of them? And what factors determine their sizes?

Comment: Instruction alignment for functions and jump targets? This has been asked before.

Comment: Why functions need alignment? And it seems jump targets (basic block first-instruction address) do not need alignment.

Comment: Jump targets should also be aligned. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24135535/547981).

Comment: Just take a look at x86_64 Linux machine code, the jump target can start from any address.

Comment: You get better cache performance when the start of a function is cache-line aligned.

Comment: @WindChaser: Doesn't need to, but often is. As I said, you should find plenty of material on this website. Search around a bit.

Comment: Like my L1 icache size is 64, cache-line alignment means we can align by 16,32,or 64; or only 64? Since I see a lot of jump targets or function entry points are aligned to 32 bytes instead of 64 after inserting NOOPs before them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4486485/11287
...Modern x86 assemblers use the largest possible NOP opcodes..." 
But I have no idea why the same loop optimized algorithm is used for functions alignment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7364850/11287 - explains why you still see this "optimization" between functions.